# CSS transitions only work the first time they are applied

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, css-transitions

As part of an AngularJS app I'm creating I've got a list of records that're broken up in to 3 sections: 
A list of the records before the currently selected record, the currently selected record and then a list of records after the currently selected record. Both lists of records and the currently selected record are created from a single parent list of all records (the order of records in this list of all records doesn't change). So the basic HTML structure looks like this:

```
<div class="card list" ng-repeat="timeRecord in recordsBeforeCurrent">
    ....
</div>
<div class="card" ng-class="active" id="currentRecordCard">
    ....
    <h2 ng-class="activeTimer" id="currentRecordTimer"></h2>
    ....
</div>
<div class="card list" ng-repeat="timeRecord in recordsAfterCurrent">
    ....
</div>
```

Whenever the currently selected record changes I want to be able to apply css transitions to the `currentRecordCard` element and the `currentRecordTimer` element. I do this using the following css:

```
#currentRecordCard {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    transition: margin 1s ease;
}

#currentRecordCard.active {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#currentRecordTimer {
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 16px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#currentRecordTimer.activeTimer {
    font-size: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -57px;
}
```

Each time the user clicks on a record in either of the `recordsBeforeCurren`t or `recordsAfterCurrent` lists, a function `resumeRecord()` is called which currently looks like this:

```
$scope.resumeRecord = function(record){
    $scope.active = "";
    $scope.activeTimer = "";


    *** 
        currentRecord = null;
        lists of before and after records are cleared;
        currentRecord is set whichever record was just clicked;
        lists of before and after records are recalculated;
    ***

    $scope.active = "active";
    $scope.activeTimer = "activeTimer";
}
```

Currently the transitions work correctly the first time that the `currentRecord` is changed but every time after that, when the `currentRecord` is changed there are no transitions and the `.active` and `.activeTimer` class attributes are always active so I'm not too sure what the issue is...

Cheers

Comment: if you are just adding css class you can use `ng-class`.Currently,  you are not doing it Angular way.

Comment: @maddog Ok I've just changed the code to use ng-class but unfortunately it doesn't seem to make a difference :/

Comment: would it be possible to make a plunkr? as i m not sure how you using `timeRecord` from `ng-repeat`

Comment: To be completely sure, you mean the style are applied, but they "snap" with no animation, correct? Also what browser are you testing this in?

Comment: Do you really have to break list into 3 parts? Why?

Comment: @GregRozmarynowycz yes that's correct. I've tested in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: @RuslanasBalčiūnas I only did this because it seemed the simplest way to be able to apply separate styles to a single element in a list of ng-repeat items. This app is the first time I've used AngularJS.

Comment: If you inspect the element(s) in Chrome, with the classes applied, are the transition rules "active" or overridden (crossed out) by something else? I did a fiddle using a jQuery swapping out similar classes and didn't have any issues.

Comment: @GregRozmarynowycz http://s24.postimg.org/avsyxrk9x/Untitled.jpg

Comment: The inspector screenshot kind of disproves this, but maybe the styles are being directly applied by angular after the first time, other than that there's not much else I can think of.

Comment: @GregRozmarynowycz If this is the case, is there an obvious fix?

Comment: Did you see my solution? Check Plunkr link. Is it what you wanted?

Comment: @RuslanasBalčiūnas Just saw your Plunkr link. That's actually very close to what I'm after thanks but I'm not quite sure if it'll work seeing as there needs to be 2 separate lists seeing as they are split up into separate cards. I'll have a play around with it though and see if I can figure something out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this. Test it in [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/MbXIXxKn3kesjILZSf1i).

```
<div class="card list"
     ng-class="currentRecord === $index ? 'active' : ''"
     ng-click="toggleRecord($index)"
     ng-repeat="timeRecord in records">
     <h2></h2>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$scope.toggleRecord = function($index) {
    $scope.currentRecord = $index;
}
```

CSS

```
.card {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    transition: margin 1s ease;
}

.card.active {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.card h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 16px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.card.active h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -57px;
}
```

Comment: Because I need the list to be split into 3 separate cards I'm not sure if this will work.

Comment: Unfortunately not sorry. I think my main issue is that I still need a parent div with the class `card` around the list before and after the current record otherwise every element in the list will end up being in its own separate card.

Comment: Ok. You may check my last attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this working the way I wanted. I ended up having to change some logic in the controller and create my own classes for the cards (I'm using Ionic so was hoping to use their classes) so that there is only a single list for every record. A big thanks to everyone who helped me, particularly Ruslanas Balčiūnas with your Plunkr which made things much easier for me.